# POST Request with content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is not working in server(QA,UAT...) but works fine locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Below is my POST Request

```
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
 if (timeoutOverride.HasValue)
        {
            timeout = timeoutOverride.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            timeout = GetTimeoutForUrl(request.RequestUri);
        }

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(data);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

       var asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
        string responseData;
        try
        {
            using (asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle)
            {
                bool complete = asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout);
                if (!complete)
                {
                    ThrowTimeoutError(url, timeout);
                }
                using (var webResponse = request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
                {
                    using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var responseStreamReader = new                StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            responseData = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

please help me out , how to make it work on server, i am thinking it is server configuration issue. or else issue with my request, it works locally fine, not working on server.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify MIME types in server

IIS settings, MIME types needs to included.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045

Comment: Hi , Thanks for response. i have just added MIME Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and extension type as ".CS" ....but still not working, do know any other changes..plz help me out  ?